# Не отображаются символы юникод

Tags: c#, unicode

В Label.text записывает тот или иной символ юникода, например,  `Label.text = "\u20BD";`. На одном компьютере эти символы отображаются как надо, а на другом вместо них пустые квадраты. По какой причине это происходит, и что надо сделать, чтоб все верно отображалось на всех компьютерах?

Comment: А шрифты одни и те же используются?

Comment: @ixSci, вместо стандартного при разработке указан Arial. Видимо если этого шрифта нет на другом, компьютере, а в другом шрифте такого символа нет, то будут квадраты вместо него?

Comment: Arial должен быть везде, но вот на всех ли машинах он имеет последнюю версию, в которой есть(?) символ рубля? Если шрифт не знает, как нарисовать символ будут квадраты, да.

Comment: @ixSci, да, именно с рублем такая вещь. Не подскажите как правильно поступить в такой ситуации: шрифт по умолчанию оставить (если он содержит всегда все символы, конечно)  или еще может что-то еще предпринять можно?

Comment: Я с такой ситуацией никогда не сталкивался, но я бы, наверное, таскал бы нужный шрифт с программой и его бы использовал. Предварительно узнав все легальные стороны этого вопроса.

Comment: @ixSci, ясно, спасибо за информацию

Comment: @ixSci: Мне кажется, имеет смысл оформить в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Квадраты» у Вас отображаются потому, что шрифт, используемый в программе, не знает как отобразить тот или иной символ из unicode. Решить этот вопрос можно либо нахождением такого шрифта, который есть на всех машинах, на которые программа может быть установлена(сложно), либо же распространять шрифт с программой, предварительно узнав, можно ли так делать с точки зрения лицензионного соглашения, ассоциированного со шрифтом.