# C++ юникод консоль

Tags: c++, windows, консоль, unicode

Как мне в консоль вывести смайлик? Или другой unicode-символ? Windows

Comment: а консоль сможет этот смайлик показать, шрифты поддерживают?

Comment: похоже на дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493877/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%8e%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4?rq=1

Comment: Там кода нету! И плюс там си шарп

Comment: вот так работает `int main() {std::cout << "\u263a";}`

Comment: @KoVadim, а теперь то же самое, но на windows.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015571/how-to-print-unicode-character-in-c) вроде есть пример

Comment: @Qwertiy а волшебное слово? (автор вопроса не уточнял операционку)

Comment: @KoVadim, уже упомянул. Но вроде и так с кодировкой консоли проблемы обычно на винде.

Comment: ну тогда мой ответ прост - для начала установить себе линукс.

Comment: Ну, кстати, в винде же уже тоже есть несколько разных терминалов. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal

Comment: Github bash или повершелл как терминал нужно использовать.

Comment: @eri, по идее в обычной консоли тоже можно.

Comment: Если получилось, мне хотелось бы код увидеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположительно так:

1. Сменить кодировку консоли на юникодную.
2. Сменить шрифт консоли (вероятно, с помощью [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex)) на такой, в котором есть нужные символы.
3. Вывести символы с помощью `wcout`.